# Что означает синтаксис (type [, event]) в JS?

Tags: javascript, синтаксис

в частности интересует что значит [ , ...]? (троеточие имеется ввиду что-либо после запятой)

Comment: Необязательный аргумент в функции если это в документации увидели. Полностью кусок кода или документации покажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: я отдельно этот фрагмент на бумажке выписал, чтоб погуглить. а код уже не помню где попадался. в следующий раз буду более подробный кусок кода вставлять в вопрос. Благодарю за отклик!

Comment: Зачем тогда вопрос, и тем более ответ на вопрос, контекст которого утерян и вы сами не знаете о чем спрашиваете?

Answer (score 2):

Если конкретно такой случай, то как пример
**[Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)**

Синтаксис:

```
Math.max([value1[, value2[, ...]]])
```

В текущем случае всё, что это значит, количество параметров, которые можно подать на вход - неограниченное количество.  А квадратные скобки означают необязательность параметра.

---

тоже самое есть в методе **[call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)**

```
fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

и т. д.

---

В иных случаях многоточия (`...`)  могут означать что угодно, например

**[Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)** оператор или **[Rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Rest_parameters)**

Comment: `console.log( [, 12])` => `Array(2) => [0] - undefined, [1] - 12` )) Из ответа не совсем ясно - это фрагменты кода? Описание работы функции в документации?