# Что значит такая запись метода?

Tags: javascript, методы

Из [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```js
str.substring(indexA[, indexB]);
```

Зачем в записи использованы квадратные скобки? Почему, например, не записали просто как `str.substring(indexA, indexB)`. Может это значит, что второй символ не является обязательным?

Как это расшифровывается?

Comment: в квадратных скобках обычно пишут опциональные параметры в документациях. Там еще пишет *indexB: Необязательный параметр.*. Я сам когда-то думал, что это означает что мы передаем массив какой-то. А на самом деле это просто список передаваемых параметров так обозначают

Comment: а еще квадратные скобки бывают вложенными

Comment: @lith.al ага https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1297148/191482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой синтаксис в коде выдаст ошибку. Так пишут только в различных документациях или же IDE. `str.substring(indexA[, indexB]);` Эта строка говорит о том, что метод `substring` имеет два параметра на вход и один из них необязательный.

Если бы мы могли переписать это в "рабочий код" это выглядело бы так.

```
String.prototype.substring = function(start,end = this.length){
    ///код
}
```